# How to update edge features in a graph using a loss function?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, objective-functions, graphs, graph-theory

Given a directed, edge attributed graph G, where the edge attribute is a probability value, and a particular node N (with binary features f1 and f2) in G, the algorithm that I want to implement is as follows:

1. List all the outgoing edges from N, let this list be called edgelist_N.
2. For all the edges in edgelist_N, randomly assign to the edge attribute a probability value such that the sum of all the probabilities assigned to the edges in the edgelist_N equals to 1.
3. Take the top x edges (x can be a hyperparameter).
4. List the nodes in which the edges from step 3 are incoming.
5. Construct a subgraph with node N, the nodes from step 4 and the edges from step 3.
6. Embed the subgraph (preferably using a GNN) and obtain it's embedding and use it with a classifier to predict say f1/f2.
7. Propagate the loss so as to update the edge probabilities, that was assigned randomly in step 2.

I do not understand how to do step 7, i.e. update the edge attribute with the loss, so that edges which are more relevant in constructing the subgraph can be assigned a higher probability value.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE? Is this a homework problem? Is this related to geometric deep learning? What's the name of the course?